How to fix the Invalid hostname for this tenancy error when accessing files in SharePoint using Microsoft Graph API
I'm using graph API in my react project to access SharePoint files in a site called test-site-001. The main functionality is to get all the files and folder details. Below is my HTTP request and the code.
const fetchOneDriveFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/test-site-001/drive/root/children",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setFiles(data.value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
  }
};

Also, I'm getting the access token from Azure AD. Below are the scopes.
scopes: ["User.Read", "Files.Read", "Sites.Read.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All"]
And I'm getting the below error.
error: 
{
   code: "invalidRequest", 
   message: "Invalid hostname for this tenancy"
}

I'm new to the Graph API, so appreciate the help.

The error occurred as you are passing SharePoint site name instead of site ID in the API call to retrieve files.
I have one SharePoint site named sridemosite with below files and folders in it:

When I ran below API call by passing SharePoint site name to retrieve files and folders via Graph Explorer, I too got same error:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site_name/drive/root/children

Response:

To resolve the error, you need to pass Site ID of your SharePoint site that can be found with below API call:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/site_name

Response:

When I ran the API again by passing SharePoint site ID, I got the response successfully with files and folders details like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site_ID/drive/root/children

Response:

In your case, replace SharePoint site name with site ID in the URL to resolve the error.

You can access site either by a relative path or by a site id.
The URL template to access site by relative path is
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{your_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com:{your_site_name}

The response will contain the id of the site.
const fetchOneDriveFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{your_tenant_name}.sharepoint.com:test-site-001/drive/root/children",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setFiles(data.value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
  }
};

It's more common to use site id in the Graph API queries
const fetchOneDriveFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root/children",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setFiles(data.value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching files:", error);
  }
};

